# Performance differences between Swazoo and Komanche?

Tags: performance, webserver, smalltalk, seaside

I'd like to know what the performance differences between Swazoo and Komanche in general and for Seaside are. Especially **why** and **in what situations** I should prefer the one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only major differences between the two are:

1. **Swazoo is licensed under the LGPL, while Komanche is licensed under the MIT license.**  Some people are very uncomfortable using LGPL software in Smalltalk, since the definition of whether something is a library in a Smalltalk is extremely ambiguous.  If you share that concern, use Komanche.
2. **Komanche only works in Squeak/Pharo and Gemstone, while Swazoo works in most Smalltalks.** In particular, Swazoo runs in GNU Smalltalk, VisualWorks, Squeak/Pharo, Gemstone, and Dolphin.  If you're going to be working directly with the web server (which, to make this clear, is very rare), you should probably develop against Swazoo.  This should only be a factor in very unusual applications.
3. **Seaside's COMET packages only support Komanche.** So if you want COMET and Seaside, you'll need Komanche.

Otherwise, the two servers are roughly equivalent in terms of features and performance, and I don't honestly think it makes a large difference.